# Convert Fan (on 14/3) to 2 single pole Light & Outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

I have a light switch that has 14/2 (power) coming into the box, and 14/3 going out to the ceiling (where there was a fan). The 14/3 carried light/fan controls separately. I removed the fan and replaced with a standard light. I am installing a projector and would like to add an outlet on the ceiling by the light. I was hoping to use the red traveler wire as the HOT for the outlet, and somehow combine the neutrals/ground.

Essentially the black wire would carry power from the switch to the light and the red would have continuous load bypassing the switch.

Here is what I have
[image]

Here is what I tried and failed:
[image]

It should be noted that I CAN add power coming into the box if needed. Not ideal but if an extra wire coming into the box helps I can do it. There is a 3 way switch in the box as well on another circuit and an outlet nearby I can tap into. I just CANNOT run a new wire from the box to the ceiling.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What you tried should work, so if it failed, it was either not to the diagram or there was a poor connection.

Comment: Your plan should work... make sure there's no breaks in the red wire.. like another junction box

Comment: So what happened was whenever the Red in the switch box was connected to the black carrying the load, all the wires on the circuit (Black/red/white) all became hot. I've checked everywhere and there are no other runs from this circuit (and no damaged wire). The strange thing is that what I have now (without power to the red) works perfectly. But as soon as that red gets power, the switch is bypassed and ALL wires are hot. I figured it was something being carried back by the neutral.

Comment: I think the problem is that I was using one of those "quick-testers" and i was registering the neutral as Hot, but it might have just been picking up some impedance. I'll retest tonight with my multi-meter.

Comment: Since you have a multimeter, switch off the power at the breaker and check resistance between the red wire (disconnected from the feed as you have it now) and the other wires. It should be infinite. If it's not, there's a connection not shown here.

Comment: I'll try that this evening and report back. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Neutral will be hot if it's disconnected between there and the panel.  The #1 issue I see is the confusing splash of colors.  I would use black for always-hot and red as switched-hot.  That way, in each box, it's real simple: all black goes together and all red goes together (mark the lamp wire as red).

Comment: Good feedback around the neutral. I will check on that. The colors chosen are to represent the actual colors of the wires in the box, except Green is ground. The problem is I was seeing various wires become energized so in my second diagram all wires would be black, as they all "appeared" to be hot.

Comment: @ecnerwal make that an answer and as someone that dose this for a living I will up vote, I have recently started suggesting DIY use WAGO lever lock connectors, I don’t know why but many new diy just don’t do wire nuts right.  The lever locks are rated for 32 amps so they work goof on 12& 14 awg connections not sold on 10 yet but if wired as shown it would work+

Comment: I want to confirm that it did work as mentioned above. The problem was my tester was not correct as I wasn't using a true voltage meter and my tester was just measuring impedance I believe.  If @Ecnerwal want's to answer this I'll confirm it so you get the credit.